# Trigger an action throught the console

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I've SMTP service, which have to trigger on some action.
The service was just running in static Main() of Program(default by console).
Now i'm refactoring it into HostService

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            const string _appsettings = "appsettings.json";

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                    {
                        config.AddJsonFile(_appsettings, true);
                        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();

                        if (args != null)
                        {
                            config.AddCommandLine(args);
                        }
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services.AddOptions();
                        services.Configure<MailSettings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
                        services.Configure<RabbitMQSettings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQSettings"));

                        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MailingService>();
                    });

            await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
        }
```

Now i wannt build service which will trigger the action:

```
public class MailingService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly IMailService _mailService;
        private readonly IOptions<MailSettings> _mailSettings;
        private readonly IOptions<RabbitMQSettings> _rabbitSettings;

        public MailingService(IOptions<MailSettings> mailSettings, IOptions<RabbitMQSettings> rabbitSettings,
            IMailService mailService)
        {
            _mailService = mailService;
            _mailSettings = mailSettings;
            _rabbitSettings = rabbitSettings;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = _rabbitSettings.Value.HostName,
                UserName = _rabbitSettings.Value.UserName,
                Password = _rabbitSettings.Value.Password,
                Port = _rabbitSettings.Value.Port,
                VirtualHost = _rabbitSettings.Value.VirtualHost,
                AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = _rabbitSettings.Value.AutomaticRecoveryEnabled
            };

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

This code is how my app was running in Program stativ void Main()

```
      IOptions<MailSettings> _mailSettings = Options.Create(new
      MailSettings());
                  MailService mailService = new MailService(_mailSettings);
          
                  var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
                  {
                      HostName = "localhost",
                      UserName = "guest",
                      Password = "guest",
                      Port = 5672,
                      VirtualHost = "/",
                      AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true
                  };
          
                  IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                  IModel model = connection.CreateModel();
          
                  model.QueueDeclare(queue: "order",
                              durable: false,
                              exclusive: false,
                              autoDelete: false,
                              arguments: null);
          
                  var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
          
                  consumer.Received += async (sender, e) =>
                  {
                      var body = Deserialize<Mail>(e.Body.ToArray());
                      await mailService.SendMessageAsync(body);
                  };
          
          
                  while (true)
                  {
                      model.BasicConsume("order", true, consumer);
                  }
```

Now, i'm pondering how and where I have to move the

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                      IModel model = connection.CreateModel();
model.QueueDeclare(queue: "order" ...
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(model);
```

And of course the event:

```
consumer.Received += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var body = Deserialize<Mail>(e.Body.ToArray());
    await mailService.SendMessageAsync(body);
};
              
              
                          model.BasicConsume("order", true, consumer);
```

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: @Serge, the questing is how and where i have to move rabbit initialization and trigger(consumer.Received) put in the service? in which of func?